# Cakephp find returning null values for associated model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I have two models A and B. Relationships are defined as mentioned below.

```
A hasOne B
B belongsTo A
```

Everything was working great till a few days back. In last couple of days something has changes and now when I do a find on A (with recursive set to 2), it returns the values of B but all values are returned as NULL including the ID of B.

```
A (id - 1220, other_fields)
B (id - 11, a_id - 1220, other_fields)
```

Resulting array looks like this.

```
array(
  'A' => array(
    'id' => 1220,
    'field1' => 'dsdsa',
    ...
  )
  'B' => array(
    'id' => null,
    'a_id' => null,
    ...
  )
)
```

I have verified in database that row for B exists corresponding to A. I even tried executing the Host find query (copied from SQL debug dump) and it returns the results correctly so nothing wrong at database level. It's cake (or myself) which is messing up with the data.

It was all working fine but something has gone wrong and I am having hard time trying to figure out what.

Here is the query (replace Host with A and Service with B)

```
SELECT `Host`.`id`, `Host`.`user_id`, `Host`.`title`, `Host`.`featured`, `Host`.`slug`, `Host`.`profile_type`, `Host`.`social_security_number`, `Host`.`biz_id`, `Host`.`address`, `Host`.`lat`, `Host`.`lon`, `Host`.`description`, `Host`.`type`, `Host`.`size`, `Host`.`unavailability`, `Host`.`kids`, `Host`.`supervision`, `Host`.`emergency_transport`, `Host`.`experience`, `Host`.`first_aid`, `Host`.`oral_medication`, `Host`.`injected_medication`, `Host`.`payment_mode`, `Host`.`paypal_email`, `Host`.`name_on_check`, `Host`.`payment_address`, `Host`.`bank_name`, `Host`.`bank_account_number`, `Host`.`balance`, `Host`.`pending_balance`, `Host`.`approved`, `Host`.`created`, `Host`.`modified`, `Service`.`id`, `Service`.`host_id`, `Service`.`day_care`, `Service`.`day_care_price`, `Service`.`day_night_care`, `Service`.`day_night_care_price`, `Service`.`walking`, `Service`.`walking_price`, `Service`.`walking_max_distance`, `Service`.`checkup_visit`, `Service`.`checkup_visit_price`, `Service`.`checkup_visit_max_distance`, `Service`.`grooming`, `Service`.`grooming_price`, `Service`.`bathing`, `Service`.`bathing_price`, `Service`.`pickndrop`, `Service`.`pickndrop_price`, `Service`.`training`, `Service`.`training_price`, `Service`.`cancellation_policy`, `Service`.`accept_last_min_bookings`, `Service`.`created`, `Service`.`modified` FROM `hosts` AS `Host` LEFT JOIN `services` AS `Service` ON (`Service`.`host_id` = `Host`.`id`) WHERE `Host`.`id` = 2569 ORDER BY `Host`.`created` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Did you change anything in the code? Or the database?

Comment: Can you include the SQL query that CakePHP uses to retrieve the data? If you set debug to 2 (inside `app/Config/core.php`), the queries performed should be visible on your page. Just be sure to only add the relevant query(ies). You can append it to your question via the [edit] link

Comment: @LSA I wish I knew what I changed.

Comment: Do you have afterFind functions in your models? Maybe that changed...

Comment: @thaJeztah I have checked the query as mentioned in the question and it's fine. It returns the results as expected. I have pasted the query above. You can replace Host with A and Service with B to correlate it with the question.

Comment: @nuns Noup, not afterFind() callback is being used.

Comment: Post the find function and the relationqship, we may find something

Comment: @Vikram thanks for adding that, at least we narrowed it down to not being *invalid* SQL statements and since you manually ran the query and it returned the data as expected, it's not the data in the database. Are you using **behaviors** that may perform some `afterFind()`? Apart from that, not really an idea. It may be worth installing [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) and placing break points to check *where* the data gets lost

Comment: @thaJeztah No behaviors or plugin are in use which make afterFind call. I'll try the setting the breakpoints, hopefully that'll give some clue.